# What is the physical significance of crest and trough in an electromagnetic wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, electric-fields, interference

Lets say an electron is vibrating at its mean position. From what I've gathered a crest would be its motion in one direction and a trough would be its motion in another direction. So first of all is that correct?

And if that is correct, will the electric fields created by the electron in one direction be any different from the electric fields created in another direction? I ask that question in context of the concept of interference. Like lets say there are two (equal) light sources, for simplicity, lets say electrons kept in a double spilt experiment apparatus. And lets take a point where theres darkness (called destructive interference, i think). And what that basically means is the the crest of source one is in alignment with the trough of source 2, so they cancel out. Which in the electron sense would mean that when electron 1 is going in a particular direction electron 2 is going in the opposite direction but my confusion is  that the electron whether it goes up Or down (in one direction or opposite) is creating a negative electric field either way. Like its not possible that it creates a positive field in up and negative in down, so it cant be that one electron 1 has created positive field electron 2 has created a negative one so they cancel out when they meet. That cant be it. So why do the crest and the trough cancel out in a physical sense?

Comment: You seem to be thinking that E fields have something to do with electrons moving at the place of the E field. That is just a confusion. The E fields are doing their thing; they may be created by electrons shaking, but that does not dictate that the electrons were moving at the location of the E field.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with mechanical waves. [Wave Machine Demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VE520z_ugcU). This Jelly Baby wave machine shows that if you move one Jelly Baby up and down, you create a wave that moves away. The crest and trough are the high and low points in the wave. They match how far up and down the original Jelly Baby moved. But keep in mind the wave is a different thing from the original Jelly Baby.

For light, the situation is different. Vibrating an electron up and down generates a light wave. One way to do this is in a radio antenna. It is a long vertical wire. Electrons move up and down in it. It emits a very low frequency, long wavelength form of light called a radio wave. These are much, much longer than the wavelengths in visible light, but they are light.

When a light wave travels, they leave the electrons that generated them behind. No new electrons vibrate as they travel. These are not mechanical waves at all.

Electrons generate an electric field. (Also magnetic field, but we will gloss over that.) The field generates forces on other electrons. The field is strong near the electron and weak farther away. That is, the forces are strong near the electron and weak farther away. The field changes as you move the electron. A spot that was near the electron and used to have a strong field may now be farther away and have a weak field.

A light wave is a disturbance in the electric and magnetic fields caused by moving electrons. The field gets stronger and weaker over and over. This disturbance spreads out through space, like a wave in a wave machine or in the ocean. But only changing fields are moving.

When people talk about peaks and troughs in these fields, they mean the strongest and weakest fields. It is not how far anything moves. There is a relationship between how much the electrons move and how big the peaks and troughs are. But it isn't as direct as in a wave machine.

---

Light travels until it hits something like black paint or your eye. These contain atoms. Atoms contain electrons. The changing electric field in the light wave exerts forces on the electrons, and makes them vibrate up and down. This absorbs the light. The energy in the light may go into heating black paint, or exciting nerves to produce vision.

As light passes through air, it passes by atoms that contain electrons. These electrons are tightly tied to the nucleus of the atoms, and so do not vibrate in response to the forces from the changing electric field. Light and air have no effect on each other. This is why air is invisible.

---

You can have two waves in a wave machine at the same time. Two people at opposite ends can move a Jelly Baby up and down. Two waves will travel toward each other and pass through each other.

As they do, the movement of a Jelly Baby is the sum of the movements of each wave. As two crests pass each other, both push the Jelly Baby up. The Jelly Baby moves up twice as far as it would for one wave.

Likewise when a crest passes a trough, one wave pushes a Jelly Baby up and the other pushes it down. These cancel, and the Jelly Baby left at the center height.

Light waves are not mechanical vibrations, but they act in a similar way to mechanical waves. If two light waves line up so that two crests hit an electron at the same time, both push the electron up. The electron moves up twice as much.

If they line up so that one crest arrives at the same time as the trough of the other wave, the electron doesn't get pushed anywhere.

In practice, it is hard to arrange two different visible light waves to coincide like that. At one instant, you might have two crests hitting an electron. But a billionth of a second later, it might be a crest and a trough. So what you see is an average of all the possible arrangements of crest and trough.